# Get AttributeError when copying string from a file into a new file

Tags: python, file, copy

I am writing a simple program that reads a file, copies its contents and writes the copied content into a new file. I thought I had done it correctly, because when I open `"copyFile"` the copied contents of the original file is written there as a string. I've written:

```
copy = open('TestFile').read()                   #Open 'TestFile', read it into variable
print("Copy of textfile:\t", copy)

copyFile = open('copyText.txt', 'w').write(copy) #Create new file, write in the copied text
copyText = copyFile.read()
print("New file :\t", copyText)
```

And I am able to print the contents of the file, but when I try to print the copy, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "PATH/TO/THE/FILE/CALLED/copyText.py", line 14, in <module>
        copyText = copyFile.read()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The file only has one sentence in it, so I don't understand the error i'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- File `write` do not return `io` object. It returns length of the text written.
- Also i suggest you should use with statement to write and read from file.
- The following code is the right way to do it for your case.

```py
copy = open('TestFile').read()                   #Open 'TestFile', read it into variable
print("Copy of textfile:\t", copy)

length = open('copyText.txt', 'w').write(copy) #Create new file, write in the copied text
copyText = open('copyText.txt', 'r').read()
print("New file :\t", copyText)
```

- This is the solution you should use to read and write.

```py
with open('TestFile', 'r') as readfile:
    copy = readfile.read()
print("Copy of textfile:\t", copy)
with open("copyTest.txt", 'w') as writefile:
    length = writefile.write(copy)
print("Length written to file", length)
with open("copyTest.txt", 'r') as readfile:
    copyText = readfile.read()
print("New file:\t", copyText)
```

output

```
Copy of textfile:    this is a sentence

Length written to file 19
New file:    this is a sentence
```

TestFile:

> this is a sentence

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `write` function is outputting the number of characters that were written to the file, which means you are trying to call `read` on an `int`.

You'll want to store the file in a variable before trying to write to it, if you want to read in the file text afterwards. This can be achieved like the following

```
copy = open('TestFile').read()                   #Open 'TestFile', read it into variable
print("Copy of textfile:\t", copy)

copyFile = open('copyText.txt', 'w') #Create new file
copyFile.write(copy) # write in the copied text
copyText = copyFile.read()
print("New file :\t", copyText)
```